# How to turn a string to a DateTime object in .NET Micro?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-micro-framework

I am wondering if there is an easy way to turn a string like: `110811124209.197` into a datetime object where the format is `yymmddhhmmss.sss`. If was were using regular .net I would just use

```
DateTime.ParseExact(MyDateString, "yyMMddHHmmtt.ttt");
```

but it would seem that ParseExact is not apart DateTime in .net micro

Comment: Why does the code have 't'(s) in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the string apart manually and use this constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb249tb7.aspx

```
public DateTime(
    int year,
    int month,
    int day,
    int hour,
    int minute,
    int second,
    int millisecond
)
```

You can use String.Substring to split it apart:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx

Comment: I had thought I would have to use the constructor. Anther newbie question. How to change string to int?

Comment: Use the int.Parse("2011") function.